# I cannot get the google-attention-ocr

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr

I am new in Tensorflow and I am trying to build model which will be able to perform OCR on my images. I am reading the paper of google about the attention ocr.the  project in github seems non-existent.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr

Answer (score 1):

The project moved into the `research` subfolder of `tensorflow/models`.
The new correct link is:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr

Comment: Ok，this is really the correct link. Thanks Alexander.